# Less number of threads are running parallel - Spring Batch Remote Partitioning

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-batch

I am working on a Spring Batch project where I have a file of 2 million records. I am doing some processing on it and then saving it to database. Processing is time costly. So I am using Spring Batch Remote partitioning.

First I am manually splitting the file into 15 files and then using multiResourcePartitioner I am assigning each file to a single thread. But what I noticed is that in the start only 4 threads are running parallel and after some time number of threads running parallel are decreasing with time.

This is the configuration:

```
 <batch:job id="GhanshyamESCatalogUpdater">
    <batch:step id="GhanshyamCatalogUpdater2" >
        <batch:partition step="slave" partitioner="rangePartitioner">
            <batch:handler grid-size="15" task-executor="taskExecutor" />
        </batch:partition>
    </batch:step>

    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="jobFailureListener"/>
    </batch:listeners>
</batch:job>

<bean id="rangePartitioner" class="org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.MultiResourcePartitioner" scope="step">
<property name="resources" value="file:#{jobParameters['job.partitionDir']}/x*">
</property>
</bean>

<step id="slave" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch">
<tasklet>
<chunk reader="gsbmyntraXmlReader" writer="gsbmyntraESWriter" commit-interval="1000" />
</tasklet>
</step>
```

This is the Task Executor:

```
<bean id="taskExecutor"
      class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="100" />
    <property name="allowCoreThreadTimeOut" value="true" />
    <property name="WaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @RomanC I am reading data from a file and then i am making a object from this data and then saving this data to DB. But making object is time Costly as it makes some network calls. So i want to process the data parallely. I am using remote partitioning and creating 15 threads. But all threads are not running parallel.

Comment: Please share your configuration of your job with us. And on what kind of hardware are you running the job?

Comment: @HansjoergWingeier I added the configuration.

Comment: How is the taskececutor configured?

Comment: @HansjoergWingeier I added the task executor.

Comment: Could you try to use a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor?

Comment: @HansjoergWingeier I tried that also
But same result.

Comment: Can you check with a breakpoint in the partition methode of Multiresourcepatitioner, that really the right 15 resources are instantiated?

Comment: @HansjoergWingeier Yes I checked that length of resource array is 14(as desired).

Comment: next, check in the handle method of TaskExecutorPartitionHandler if a FutureTask is created for every partition. if that is the case, then you have to debug into the TaskExecutor and check, why it only creates 4 threads.

Comment: @HansjoergWingeier I think threads all threads are created but those are not running parallel. I printed name of thread in writer. There all thread names were coming but those were coming in pair of 4. Means first there will be four threads and after long scrolling down there will be other four. So I think all threads are not running parallel.

Comment: how many cores has your machine? it could be, that this is some kind of optimisation. E.g., if you have 4 cores, it only runs 4 threads as a default... however, that is just a guess. If you really wanna know why it runs only 4 threads in parallel, you have to debug into the TaskExecutor-class and into the ThreadFactory.

Comment: @HansjoergWingeier My machine has four cores.